# How to render the colloquial "You've got competition!" into French

Tags: anglais, allemand

In conversation, I just said:

> Je vais prendre exemple sur eux et me mettre à faire ces choses avec autant d’élégance ! **Vous allez voir ce que vous allez voir**, mesdemoiselles !

Here I wanted to jokingly express the idea of "*You've got competition (from me), ladies!*" or "*Expect competition (from me), ladies!*". In German, a rather literally translated phrasing works fine:

> Ich werde in ihre Fußstapfen treten und jetzt auch auf diese elegante Art und Weise damit anfangen! **Ihr bekommt Konkurrenz**, Damen!

Does my phrasing work well enough? How is this idea commonly/effectively  expressed in French?

Answer (score 1):

*Vous allez voir ce que vous allez voir* is fine and idiomatic although the "competition" side is missing. It is not rude, it just tells to prepare to see an outstanding performance.

A closer expression might be:

> *Vous allez avoir de la concurrence, mesdemoiselles !*

Comment: Is my phrasing closer to "*Vous verrez ce dont je suis capable !*" without a *vis-à-vis* connotation?

Comment: Answered meantime in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

"Vous allez voir ce que vous allez voir" can often be a little rude, whereas "You've got competition" carries almost no feelings of animosity, and most likely none a all in the present case; this English phrase situates the interaction on the general level of adversity. It is more aptly expressed here by means of a turn using the verb  "concurrencer" or the noun "concurrence";

- Vous allez avoir de la concurrence
- Voilà de la concurrence pour vous
- Vous allez être concurrencées
- Vous pouvez vous attendre à de la concurrence
- Je vais vous faire concurrence